# Google App Maker not reocognising some of its own widgets

Tags: google-app-maker

In Google App Maker, I have several widgets on a page.
One of these widgets is called `Label12` (shown in Screenshot 1).
It definitely exists and is also shown in the breadcrumb trail at the top of my screen.

However, when I attempt to reference `Label12` in my code, it does not seem to exist.

If I use the ctrl+space code completion helper, the `Label12` widget is not shown as an option (shown in screenshot 2).

When I attempt to code it manually (e.g. `app.pages.Reconciliation_Details.descendants.Label12.visible`) it returns the error "Cannot set property 'visible' of undefined".

**Why can App Maker not see Label12**?

Screenshot 1 showing `Label12` on page:
[image: Screenshot 1 showing Label12]

Screenshot 2 showing absence of `Label12` when coding:
[image: Screenshot 2 showing absence of 'Label12' when coding]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Maker can see **Label12**. The point is that the label is inside a table widget, hence according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/data-widgets#table):

> Because a table is a collection of other widgets, you can't use the Widget API to interact with a table. However, you can use scripts to manipulate the individual widgets that make up a table.

The above statement makes sense because the amount of rows a table will display depends on the datasource items; i.e., the rows are dynamically created when the widget datasource is loaded in the ui. Therefore, in order to access the label you need to first access the children of the **Table1Body**, which is a collection of named values known as [PropertyMap](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#PropertyMap).

I believe you are trying to hide/show that specific label based on some logic. The correct way of doing it would be something like this:

```
var rows = app.pages.Reconciliation_Details.descendants.Table1Body.children._values;
for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
    var row = rows[i];
    var label = row.descendants.Label12;
    label.visible = true; // or false
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. Thank you!